# Матрица, заполненная случайными целыми числами

Tags: python

> Создайте матрицу (список из вложенных списков) размера N x M (фиксируются в программе), заполненную случайными целыми числами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать модуль `random` для получения случайных чисел.

***Пример:***

```py
import random


def main():
    n = 3
    m = 4

    matrix = [[random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]
    print(*matrix, sep='\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***Возможный `stdout`:***

```py
[4, 3, 9, 9]
[9, 3, 3, 8]
[7, 0, 3, 2]
```